# Custom Navigation for iOS using Titanium

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

I am new to mobile development and using Titanium.I just want to use custom navigation control in my app that provide the name of last screen instead of Back Button as my Left Navigation Button in the navigation bar.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Khrone,I have implemented the navigation using Back button(navigation window API),but i just wish to display the name of last screen(say < Menu instead  of < Back) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this person already did most of the work for you.

https://github.com/mcvendrell/Basic-custom-NavBar

Google Search: custom navbar titanium

Comment: thanks for your comment Martin!!!!but this example of github uses the depreciated Api.Though I found the same example with new API(Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow).link is    https://github.com/vuinguyen/NavControlTi32/blob/master/app/lib/NavigationController.js